# Comparison method violates its general contract Exception In NetBeans 7.1

Tags: java, exception, comparison, netbeans-7

The following exception occurs when i compile the below code in netbeans 7.1 with jre 1.7. (JRE v 7.0.20.13) The exception is thrown the highlighted portion of Code.Before i used the same code several times and the code works a bsolutely corrext for me but now suddenly the exception occurs.

**Edit:Stack Trace:**

```
 JewelleryERPApplication/build/classes/java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Comparison method violates its general contract!
at java.util.TimSort.mergeHi(TimSort.java:868)
at java.util.TimSort.mergeAt(TimSort.java:485)
at java.util.TimSort.mergeForceCollapse(TimSort.java:426)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:223)
at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:173)
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:659)
at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:217)
at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.enumerateAndSortCycle(SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.java:136)
at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getFocusTraversalCycle(SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.java:110)
at javax.swing.SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.getComponentAfter(SortingFocusTraversalPolicy.java:280)
at javax.swing.LayoutFocusTraversalPolicy.getComponentAfter(LayoutFocusTraversalPolicy.java:106)
at java.awt.Component.getNextFocusCandidate(Component.java:7860)
at java.awt.Component.transferFocus(Component.java:7828)
at java.awt.Component.disable(Component.java:1517)
at javax.swing.JComponent.disable(JComponent.java:3635)
at java.awt.Component.enable(Component.java:1495)
at java.awt.Component.setEnabled(Component.java:1458)
at javax.swing.JComponent.setEnabled(JComponent.java:2677)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.setEnabled(AbstractButton.java:2087)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Stone.EmpTrans.compEnableDisable(EmpTrans.java:215)
at jewelleryerpapplication.GUI.Stone.EmpTrans.btnEditActionPerformed(EmpTrans.java:2513)
```

**// Souce Code At Which Exception Occurs**

```
 switch (mode) {
        case "N"://New
            btnSave.setEnabled(!enable);

            btnNew.setEnabled(enable);
            **btnEdit.setEnabled(enable);**
            btnSearch.setEnabled(enable);
            btnPrint.setEnabled(enable);
            txtVchNo.setEditable(enable);
            btnExecute.setVisible(enable);
            cbDateChk.setVisible(enable);
            cbDateChk.setSelected(enable);

            isNew = true;
            isEdit = false;
            break;
         case "E":
            btnSave.setEnabled(!enable);

            btnNew.setEnabled(enable);
            **btnEdit.setEnabled(enable);**
            btnSearch.setEnabled(enable);
            btnPrint.setEnabled(enable);
            txtVchNo.setEditable(enable);
            btnExecute.setVisible(enable);
            cbDateChk.setVisible(enable);
            cbDateChk.setSelected(enable);

            isNew = false;
            isEdit = true;
            break;
          }
```

Comment: Before did u used the same jre 1.6 over here ? Bcz Netbeans 7.1 is build with jre 7 @Syed Muhammad Muba

Comment: yes i am using 1.7 (7.0.20.38). I wrongly mentioned it, made correction now.

Comment: Can u please add the stack trace over here?And Also it will be helpful if its with line number in your source @Syed Muhammad Mubashir

Comment: @theunlucky i added the stack trace for exception